# Solve $y' = y^2x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Given the differential equation $y' = y^2x$, what are the solutions to y? Obviously this is not a linear differential equation, which I'm used to solving. I checked if it is separable, which would make it easier to solve, and I ended up with the solution $y= \frac{2}{x^2+c}$, where c is the constant. Are there more solutions to this I'm missing?

Comment: Your solution is almost correct, it's just off by a sign. Remember that when you integrate the left side, you have $\frac{y'}{y^2}$, whose antiderivative is $\color{red}{-}\frac1y$.

Comment: $y=0$ is also a solution.

Comment: @user170231 so $-\frac{2}{x^2+c}$ would be correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By inspection, $y=0$ is a solution. Then

$$\frac{y'}{y^2}=x$$ and by integration

$$-\frac1y=\frac{x^2}2+c.$$